# White screen after splashscreen, Ionic2, android device

Tags: ionic2

I am currently developing Ionic2 app. I face a problem that after Splash screen, there is a white screen for 6-7 seconds, before app home screen.

I tried some googling but nothing works. My last attempt to solve is

```
    hideSplashScreen() {
    if(Splashscreen){
      setTimeout(() => {
        Splashscreen.hide();
      },100)
    }
  };//

<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
```

Please help me in this issue;

EDIT:: My `ionic info` is

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
```

Comment: which RC version of ionic are you using?

Comment: please see the EDIT.

Comment: I upgraded to RC5 and change/copy some code in **config.xml** from an official ionic app and the problem seems solved without any tricks and now load correctly and fast.
If you need more details, I can add a reply with infos.

Comment: @mosca90 , can you kindly post the complete answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Updating **Ionic project** and change some preferences did the trick for me.

Here the [changelog and infos](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

1 - Update to the latest version of the `Ionic CLI`, `Cordova` and `Typescript`:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic cordova typescript
npm install -g ionic cordova typescript
```

2 - Update your **package.json** to match the following dependencies, remove existing **node_modules directory**, and then run `npm install`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.6",
    "typescript": "2.3.2"
  }
```

3 - Update your **config.xlm** with these preferences (live review is ok):

```
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
```

4 - Then I have copy/pasted some code that had been modified recently from [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) into my project (Ionic 2 demo and up to date app - Check the Github).

Now the application starts successfully without long splashscreen.

**ps:**

- livereview: `ionic run android -l`
- production: `ionic run android --prod --release`
- Remember that you have to hide manually the splashscreen (like @Markus Wagner said) in your **app.component.ts**: `this.platform.ready().then(() => { Splashscreen.hide(); });`

**EDIT:** Update to Ionic v3.1.1 (2017-04-28)

Comment: Thanks, i will try today.

Comment: It works, I checked on android only though not on IOS till now. Will check on Ios and accept this as answer.

Comment: Let me know, I am also interested to iOS :)

Answer (score 24):

By default, the splash screen is hidden after 3 seconds (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#configxml). But it could be that at this moment your app is not ready.

Therefore I add always the following preference to my **config.xml**:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

Instead, I hide it manually, as soon as the app is ready:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    Splashscreen.hide();
});
```

This is working on iOS as well as on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Add the --prod flag during any of the following CLI commands:

```
// If iOS
ionic emulate ios --prod
ionic build ios --prod
ionic run ios --prod


// If Android
ionic emulate android --prod
ionic build android --prod
ionic run android --prod
```

More info of build (prepare + compile) an Ionic project for a given platform
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved that issue by setting the correct parameters on config.xml

```
 <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
 <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
 <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
 <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

Then, on my platform.ready() instruction all I do is Splashscreen.hide();