# cordova splash screen Issues

Tags: cordova, ionic2, splash-screen

I am using ionic2.

Following code are used in hide whitescreen after splash.

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="100" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen"/>
  </feature>
```

and here is my app component.

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    if(navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
          setTimeout(()=> {
          navigator.splashscreen.hide();
          }, 500);
    })
```

It's work only first time.again i closed my app and opened.display the splash screen and after 10 sec display whitescreen.

My plugin version

cordova-plugin-statusbar 4.0.1
How can i fix this.

Comment: add following line in config.xml "<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />"

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.But i still display white screen after splash displayed.

Comment: If you are running in android, then keep the android updates uptodate. I mean update "android studio", "sdk" and 'gradle". then try again. else increase the "loadUrlTimeoutValue" preference value to "700000" and try again.

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544016/white-screen-after-splashscreen-ionic2-android-device

Comment: Thank u.I used increase the "loadUrlTimeoutValue" preference value to "700000".It's work.. : )

Comment: @ANISUNDAR could you please add that as an answer? It could help some other SO users facing the same issue :)

Comment: @ Sabari I update my sdk.It's wrk some times.some times its does not wrk .Still i display the whitescreen.